# Loading spinning wheel animation

Tags: android, listview, animation

I'm doing a search and populating a listview with results as they come. On top there's a bar with the text "Search in progress... " I'd like to add a small spinning wheel animation to the bar in the right corner, to show the user that work is being done.

You can see this spinning wheel in the gallery app in the top right corner when thumbnails are being loaded. Also, the same animation is shown in Astro File Manager, when files are being listed in a directory, (again top right corner).

How do I put it there?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You need to call `requestWindowFeature` in `onCreate` before `setContentView`

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.search_screen);
```

And Assuming you're using `AsyncTask` for Populating the list

`onPreExecute()` will call `setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);`

`onPostExecute()` will call `setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);`

Answer (score 13):

i did spinning progress bar in my application. Hope this will helps you.

```
progDailog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Progress_bar or give anything you want",
            "Give message like ....please wait....", true);
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                // sleep the thread, whatever time you want. 
                sleep(2000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            progDailog.dismiss();
        }
    }.start();
```

if  you have still doubts, pls let me know.

Comment: Can you explain what sleep is doing here exactly? Thanks in advance

Comment: Replace sleep with your long-running operation.

Answer (score 6):

```
        ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(youravtivity.this);
        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading. Please wait...");
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        dialog.show();
```

Comment: also when the long running job is done, call "dialog.dismiss()"