# Android pop up spinning loader

Tags: android, popup, loading

I'm creating an android app where user loads some data from an online server when he hits a button

I need to add the following :
when user hits the button a pop-up screen shows on top of current screen & shows something like
"loading" "spinning loader" or anything like this
any thoughts ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loading spinning wheel animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5295001/loading-spinning-wheel-animation)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at [this Android Developer page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) at the section "Creating a ProgressDialog". Android offers such a dialog out of the box.

Comment: Ok I have a problem rising
here's my code :

onclick code :
{
ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(SP_NativeActivity.this, "", "Loading. Please wait...", true);
// load data from server

}


the problem is :

the data first get loaded then the pop up shows !!

Answer (score 3):

You can try a function like `showProgressDialog(Activity activity)`with this context:

```
if ((mySpinnerDialog== null) || (!mySpinnerDialog.isShowing())) {
        mySpinnerDialog= new Dialog(activity);
        mySpinnerDialog.getWindow().getCurrentFocus();
        mySpinnerDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        mySpinnerDialog.setContentView(R.layout.some_layout);
        mySpinnerDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mySpinnerDialog.setOwnerActivity(activity);

        mySpinnerDialog.show();
    } else {
        mySpinnerDialog.setOwnerActivity(activity);
    }
```

and dismiss this with `mySpinnerDialog.dismiss();`. Handle `Illegalargumentexception` on `dismiss()`