# How do I make a "busy wheel" (or the equivalent) in android?

Tags: android

I have an activity that on click of a button contacts the server, waits for the response and then changes to a different activity according to the response. I have that covered, but the waiting time is a bit long, so I want to have a way to tell the user that his info is being processed and that the app is not stuck, but that it's working. I was thinking of making a spinning circle appear to indicate work is being done. How do I make this happen on click? :)
(I didn't include any code, because it's mostly irrelevant, everything I have so far is working, I just need to add this small feature)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5295001/loading-spinning-wheel-animation

Comment: You are probably looking for progress bar.. There is enuf material available on how to implement progress bar..

Comment: Use a [ProgressBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html) or [ProgressDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html)?